# Can I access state inside a createAsyncThunk w/axios with redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I'm fairly new to redux toolkit so I'm still having a few issues with it!

As per the code below, I'm trying to access state (`loginDetails.username` and `loginDetails.password`) inside my `createAsyncThunk`. I'm obviously doing something wrong here - I've tried writing the `createAsyncThunk` function inside a different file, attempting to access the state inside that file and then importing the function, but either way it's failing.

```
// Import: Packages
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

// AsyncThunk: getUserDetails
export const getUserDetails = createAsyncThunk(
  "userDetails/getUserDetails",
  async () => {
    try {
      const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_URL;

      var config = {
        method: "get",
        url: `${apiUrl}/claimSet?UserName=${state.loginDetails.username}&Password=${state.loginDetails.password}`,
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",
        },
      };

      const response = await axios(config);
      const data = await response.data;
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);

// Slice: userDetailsSlice
export const userDetailsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userDetails",
  initialState: {
    loginDetails: {
      username: "",
      password: "",
    },
    details: [],
    status: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    addUsername: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loginDetails.username = payload;
    },
    addPassword: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loginDetails.password = payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [getUserDetails.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    },
    [getUserDetails.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.details = payload;
      state.status = "success";
    },
    [getUserDetails.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed";
    },
  },
});

// Actions: addUsername, addPassword
export const { addUsername, addPassword } = userDetailsSlice.actions;

// Reducer: userDetailsSlice.reducer
export default userDetailsSlice.reducer;
```

The code in the config url `${state.loginDetails.username}`, etc. is just one of many failed attempts to get hold of the state. I understand that part of the issue is that the `createAsyncThunk` is declared before the state/slide is below, but I still can't seem to find a way around it.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The async function consumes a "payload" argument, and secondly a `thunkAPI` object that contains a `getState` method.

[payloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator)

> `thunkAPI`: an object containing all of the parameters that are normally
> passed to a Redux thunk function, as well as additional options:
>
> - `dispatch`: the Redux store `dispatch` method
> - **`getState`: the Redux store `getState` method**
> - `extra`: the "extra argument" given to the thunk middleware on setup, if available
> - `requestId`: a unique string ID value that was automatically generated to identify this request sequence
> - `signal`: an `AbortController.signal` object that may be used to see if another part of the app logic has marked this request as needing
>   cancelation.
> - `rejectWithValue`: rejectWithValue is a utility function that you can return in your action creator to return a rejected response with a
>   defined payload. It will pass whatever value you give it and return it
>   in the payload of the rejected action.

```
// AsyncThunk: getUserDetails
export const getUserDetails = createAsyncThunk(
  "userDetails/getUserDetails",
  async (arg, { getState }) => { // <-- destructure getState method
    const state = getState(); // <-- invoke and access state object
    try {
      const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_URL;

      var config = {
        method: "get",
        url: `${apiUrl}/claimSet?UserName=${state.loginDetails.username}&Password=${state.loginDetails.password}`,
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",
        },
      };

      const response = await axios(config);
      const data = await response.data;
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you tell about accessing the getState in a typescript code?

Comment: @ShivamSahil I'm certain that using Typescript doesn't change how accessing the `getState` function works, it's still just destructuring assignment from the `thunkAPI` object. Are you asking more about how to type the destructuring? Does this [usage with typescript](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/412727a416c9d4503dc744c8c9a43b43838036c4/docs/usage/usage-with-typescript.md#createasyncthunk) help?

Comment: @DrewReese it gives me this error Property 'getState' does not exist on type 'void' in Typescript

Comment: export const fetchData = createAsyncThunk<unknown>(
  `${IDENTIFIER}/fetchData`,
  async ({ getState }) => {
    console.log('fetchAuditLog', getState());
  }
)

Comment: @HarshNagalla The `thunkAPI` is the ***second*** argument passed to the returned function. If your issue isn't just this trivial matter, then can you post a new question on stackoverflow with the relevant code and error details? Feel free to ping me here with a link to the new post.

Comment: In my case I had to change from createAsyncThunk('api/order', async (obj:Orders,{ rejectWithValue }) to createAsyncThunk('api/order', async (obj:Orders,{ **getState**, rejectWithValue })

Comment: I'm able to use the `getState()` method to _read_ the state, but if I try to modify an array in the state by pushing an item to the end of it, I get an error that "Cannot add property 1, object is not extensible". Is modifying the state in the async thunk not allowed?

Comment: @antun Why are you trying to mutate the state? If you want to update the state then dispatch an action, e.g. `thunkAPI.dispatch(/* action to update state */)`.

Comment: @DrewReese ah, I see, that might work. I was trying to mutate the state because there were other things I wanted to update at the same time as the asynchronous action began. I ended up solving it by putting the immediate state changes in the `extraReducers` "pending" case. Do you think it's better practice to dispatch another action, or do it in the "pending" case?

Comment: @antun The "pending" case ***is*** an action that was dispatched.  Either are valid.